# Uids in GnuPG -- 3 fields or 1

Tags: gnupg

`gpg2.1` allows me to do  `gpg2 --quick-adduid old_id new_id`.

There's no options to specify realname, email, and comment separately like in the interactive `adduid`.

Also, in listings, the three fields (realname, email, and comment) show up as merged into one line (`realname (comment) <email>`).

So are there really three fields or is it just a front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenPGP’s [User ID Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.11) is "intended to represent the name and email address of the key holder".

As a convention ([not a requirement](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/73070/12139)!), it uses the `name-addr` syntax [defined in *RFC 2822: Internet Message Format*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4).

`Name (Comment) <email-address@example.com>` is a possible variant that conforms to this syntax.

**tl;dr:** It is one field. The content is formatted like that because it’s a convention.